# What is this version of sort() which takes a container instead of two iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

I was reading Stroustrup's blog on c++ (http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/12/myths-3) when I found an intersting piece of code:

```
void do_my_sort(vector<double>& v)
{
  sort(v,[](double x, double y) { return x>y; });  // sort v in decreasing order
}

int main()
{
  vector<double> vd;
  // ... fill vd ...
  do_my_sort(v);
  // ...
}
```

Notice that the `sort` does not use the traditional `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ...)` which Stroustrup explains:

> I used a container version of `sort()` to avoid being explicit about the
>   iterators.

However, I tried the same code on my C++11 compiler but it fails to compile. I also tried the same on a C++14 compiler using ideone but it too fails to compile, saying that there is no matching call to sort.

Why is this?

Also, Stroustrup next mentions:

> I could go further and use a C++14 comparison object:
>
> `sort(v,greater<>()); // sort v in decreasing order`

I have used comparators like `great<>()` for `sort` in C++11 also. Why is he stating that this is a C++14 comparison object?

Comment: To use std::sort, you might have to #include <algorithm>

Comment: @erenon I know that and have already done that. It still says there is no matching call to sort.

Comment: There is no container version of sort in the standard, but hopefully soon: https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He wrote that himself, it is not standard. Thus you cannot find it in the standard library. You could implement it like this:

```
template <class Container, class Comp>
void sort (Container& cont, Comp comp) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::sort(begin(cont), end(cont), comp);
}
```

As Clukester pointed out, there is also [boost::sort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html) that offers this functionality.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought it was part of the language standard or was some recently introduced feature. It would be nice if he mentioned that it was a custom built function.

Comment: Why not add a default argument to the Comp template? `class Comp = less<>`?

Comment: @Mark No reason not to, I just feel that it is not relevant for the question above. I like to keep it as short and simple as possible.

Comment: Totally cheating :) Not nice Stroustrup!

Answer (score 4):

> I have used comparators like `great<>()` for sort in C++11 also. Why is he stating that this is a C++14 comparison object?

The C++14 comparison functors have the added ability to take forwarding references for its `operator()` method and deduced return types. The template argument for the [Function Objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Function_objects) collection has been changed to have a default argument of type `void` and using specialization for that type.

```
template< class T = void >
struct greater
{
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const;
};

template<>
struct greater<void>
{
    template< class T, class U>
    constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
      -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) > std::forward<U>(rhs));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he is using Boost's sort, not the standard sort as one would expect. So it's `boost::sort`, not `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Bjarne explains what this `sort()` is in the blog:

> I used a container version of `sort()` to avoid being explicit about the iterators. That is, to avoid having to write:
>
> ```cpp
> std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](double x, double y) { return x > y; });
> ```

Nowadays, C++20 has `std::ranges::sort` to offer, which can do this as well:

```cpp
std::vector<double> vd{ /* ... */ };

std::ranges::sort(vd);
// equivalent to ...
std::ranges::sort(vd.begin(), vd.end());
```

Note that this solution works for all ranges, such as `std::array`, `std::span`, `std::vector`, etc.

A way to imitate it in C++14 would be:

```cpp
// std::less<void> can be implemented in C++11 too
template <class Container, class Comp = std::less<void>>
void sort(Container&& cont, Comp comp = {}) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::sort(begin(cont), end(cont), std::move(comp));
}
```

*Note: this is very similar to @BaummitAugen's solution, however, it takes a forwarding reference to allow sorting containers which are not passed as lvalues.*

*Note: calling `std::sort` with `cont.begin()` and `cont.end()` would not work if `Container` is an array.*